# Which R version should i download on my new Laptop

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, tidyverse

I want to download r and r studio on my new hp 16gb 1tb laptop which version should I download as I heard that the latest version gives some packages and some other issues please advise.

And also I want to learn automation in R  such as automating login and download report and scheduling and any available automation course in R even if it is Udemy or any other paid site.

Comment: Personally, I think R-4.1 may be a little too fresh *today*: there is at least one bug where the popular plotting package `ggplot2` will crash with R-4.1 in RStudio (ref: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9373); it may be patched tomorrow or next week, I don't know. If this is a concern, then the pen-newest is R-4.0.5, which should suffice, and migration from 4.0.5 to 4.1.0 will not be difficult when you're ready. (This bug notwithstanding, most-recent-version is generally the best answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely get the latest version. No issues at all that I'm aware of. You have to reinstall old packages with the latest version, but given you're doing a fresh install that won't affect you.